# Need help on user permission in group

Tags: linux

Setup of NFS and NIS server

**1.** Has NFS folder `ack` and user `ack` and find below permission of ack folder including main directory & subdir. (`rwxrwx---.`) on NFS and NIS server.

```
drwxrwx---. 12 ack  ack     4096 Nov 20 18:10 ack
```

**2.** There are three users `abc`xyzhuh`all are added in`ack` group.

```
[root@xxxxxxx ~]# cat /etc/group | grep ack

ack:x:501:abc,xyz,hhh

xyz:x:567:ack

hhh:x:568:ack

abc:x:569:ack
```

**3.** Please check this file & folder permission details by created users abc or xyz or huh in mounted ack folder on user computer.

```
[root@xxxxxxxxx ~]# ls -l /home/nfsshare/ack/
total 63652

drwxrwx---  5 ack    ack        4096 Oct  2  2013 Dxx xxxter

-rwxrwx---  1 ack    ack        1751 Feb  6  2013 mozilla-firefox-1.desktop

-rw-r--r--  1 hhh hhh     6656 Nov 20 18:35 hhh.xls

drwxr-xr-x  2 abc abc    4096 Nov 20 18:41 abc folder

drwxrwx---  4 ack    ack        4096 Jun  4  2013 xxxx data

-rwxrwx---  1 ack    ack       67072 May 23  2013 xxx xxes.xls
```

I need that file or folder should created in `-rwx-rwx----` permission not in `-rw-r--r--` for `xls` file and `drwxr-xr-x` for folder so every users can edit their file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the gid bit on the folder: chmod -R g+s

By doing this all the folders and files created after setting the bit will inherit parent folders group permission so everybody on the ack group will be able to modify those files and folders.

Comment: ack folder and ack user is working on my server so i can't changes in this folder. so i did created new ilfs folder on nfs server and added xyz user in group of ilfs and change permision using this command chmod -R g+s /path of directory/ifls/
drwxrws--T   3 ilfs             ilfs             4096 Nov 21 15:26 ilfs
test.xls file permission details by created xyz user  and also trying to open lml owner file ddd.xls  showing in read-only mode.
root@xxxxxxxxx~]# ls -l /home/nfsshare/ilfs/
total 16
-rw-rwsr-- 1 lml lml 6656 Nov 20 18:11 ddd.xls
-rw-r--r-- 1 xyz   ilfs   6656 Nov 21 15:26 test.xls

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve your desired result by executing umask

```
umask 002
```

umask is user file-creation mode mask is used to determine permissions for newly created files. 002 is a permission. Since you are collaborating with users from group. it would be good for you.

You can add this to your **.bashrc** or **.bash_profile** file. Since most Linux distribution set it to defaults. Since adding this will override them.

Comment: i using nfs/nis server and on server umask is 0022 also tried to change from 0022 to 007 but same file permission showing on user side after create any file by users.

Comment: Did you add umask 007 to your server start up file. Since you are working on multi-user system. You should add it to start up file.Then, You need to re-login for the umask change take affect.

Comment: where shoule be add in if or elase?  O.o                             # By default, we want umask to get set. This sets it for non-login shell.
# Current threshold for system reserved uid/gids is 200
# You could check uidgid reservation validity in
# /usr/share/doc/setup-*/uidgid file
    if [ $UID -gt 199 ] && [ "`id -gn`" = "`id -un`" ]; then
       umask 002
    else
       umask 022
    fi#                                                            Only display echos from profile.d scripts if we are no login shell
# and interactive - otherwise just process them to set envvars

Comment: this is short /etc/bashrc format where should be add 007 in if or elase ?              # By default, we want umask to get set. This sets it for non-login shell. # Current threshold for system reserved uid/gids is 200 # You could check uidgid reservation validity in # /usr/share/doc/setup-*/uidgid file     if [ $UID -gt 199 ] && [ "id -gn" = "id -un" ]; then        umask 002 else        umask 022     fi  # Only display echos from profile.d scripts if we are no login shell
    # and interactive - otherwise just process them to set envvar